# Component doesn't work anymore after RouterReuseStrategy

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, router

after using some functions from this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831

```
constructor(private router: Router){
 // override the route reuse strategy
 this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function(){
    return false;
 }

 this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       // trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
       this.router.navigated = false;
       // if you need to scroll back to top, here is the right place
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

}

My Component doesn't show any data from the backend anymore. I even switched the git branch and it seems like it destroyed the component everywhere. What is the problem?

Comment: For clarification, I didn't even commited or pushed the functions I have added, but still even the other branches don't work anymore. They all don't get any data anymore. How is this even possible if I didn't commited or pushed.

Comment: You say that you're having issues displaying data from the backend, but the code you show doesn't have anything to do with that. Can you clarify what behavior you're seeing that makes you think the route reuse is causing an issue?

Comment: I don't know the point from where I used this functions in the constrcutor, the component doesn't work anymore. And the parent component doesn't work also. Thats the only thing I can imagine. I also heard that this.router.navigated = false; is causing problems. Maybe the backend is not the problem but something is wrong with the component. What I dont understand is why other branches are effected even though i did not commit anything.